# How can I save the progress of a word in hangman using JavaScript/React?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm creating a modified version of hangman that has a common theme and that presents all of your previous guesses on the last clue. I haven't been able to figure out how to save the exact state of the user's guesses.

Let's say the answer to a clue is 'overflow'. If the user guesses 'f v l w e', I want to later be able to show _ve_fl_w. I'm so far only able to save the letters that they guessed that are in the word and only in the order in which they guessed them.

So what I currently have just shows me 'fvlwe' at the last step. I call `checkGuessedLetter` after every keyboard entry.

```js
  checkGuessedLetter = (guessedLetter) => {
    if (this.props.answer.indexOf(guessedLetter) > -1) {
      this.setState({
        guessedLettersInAnswer: [...this.state.guessedLettersInAnswer, guessedLetter]
      });
    }
  }
```

And then when moving to the next step,

```js
  this.props.saveGuess(this.state.guessedLettersInAnswer.join(''));
```

### Edit:

I was able to React-ify Matthias' code to get close to where I want to be, but now I end up with duplicates (if the words are 'stack', 'overflow', and 'question' and I miss a few letters, I see 'st__ckst__ckoverf__owst__ckoverf__owquestion'). It's because I'm now just saving all of the letters as one long string. Can anyone help with that?

```js
  saveGuess = (answer, guessedLetters) => {
    for (var letter of answer) {
      if (guessedLetters.indexOf(letter) > -1) {
        this.setState({
          allGuesses: [...this.state.allGuesses, letter]
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          allGuesses: [...this.state.allGuesses, '__']
        });
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getHint(word,letters){
  var s='';
  for(let i=0;i<word.length;i++){
    if(letters.indexOf(word[i])!=-1) s+=word[i];
    else s+='_';
  }
  return s;
}
```

This would allow to call `getHint('overflow','fvlwe')` and it would return a value of `_ve_fl_w`. This does not use React.

Comment: Thanks; this is very close to what I need. I've been able to React-ify it, but now I end up with duplicates (if the words are 'stack', 'overflow', and 'question' and I miss a few letters, I see 'st__ckst__ckoverf__owst__ckoverf__owquestion'). I'm not sure if the problem is due to the React conversion (now edited into the question) or this code. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: I'm not completely sure unless I see your entire code, but my guess is that you have not implemented the line of code that is s=""; and clear the hint after it prints. Again I am not completely sure, but hopefully this helps.